# Python class methods changing self

Tags: python, class, methods, int, self

This isn't for anything I'm working on yet, it's just some test code as I'm just learning class methods and suck. But say I have the following code

```
class Test(int):
    def __init__(self,arg):
            self = arg

    def thing(self):
            self += 10
```

and going,
foo=Test(12) sets foo to 12. However I want it, so when I do, foo.thing(), foo increases by 10. So far, going foo.thing() just keeps it at 12. How would I change this code to do that.

Comment: Assigning `self = arg` does nothing to your new `foo` instance (it reassigns `self`, it doesn't update the `int` subclass instance). Use a `__new__` method instead; you can leave out the `__init__` safely.

Comment: `int` is a immutable, you cannot magically turn it into a mutable class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `int` is a immutable, you cannot magically turn it into a mutable type.

Your methods are no-ops. They change `self` in the local namespace, by reassigning it to something else. They no longer point to the instance. In other words, both methods leave the original instance *unaltered*.

You cannot do what you want to do with a subclass of `int`. You'll have to create a custom class from scratch using the [numeric type hooks](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) instead.

Background: `int` has a `__new__` method that assigns the actual value to `self`, and there is no `__iadd__` method to support in-place adding. The `__init__` method is not ignored, but you can leave it out altogether since `__new__` already did the work.

Assigning to `self` means you just replaced the reference to the instance with something else, you didn't *alter* anything about `self`:

```
>>> class Foo(int):
...     def __init__(self, value=0):
...         print self, type(self)
...         self = 'foobar'
...         print type(self)
... 
>>> foo = Foo(10)
10 <class '__main__.Foo'>
<type 'str'>
>>> print foo, type(foo)
10 <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Because `int` does not have a `__iadd__` in-place add method, your `self += 2` is interpreted as `self = self + 2` instead; again, you are assigning to `self` and replacing it with a new value altogether.

Comment: I see. So it only works for things like lists and such? So if I wanted to have a function that modified it, I would have to call it like this? foo = foo.dostuff() and just have the dostuff method returning a new value

Comment: @GregHornby: No, you need to do something inside the method `dostuff()` that assigns to *attributes* of `self` or calls methods *on* `self`, not assign to `self` itself.

Comment: Exactly like that; but `int` objects have no such attribute I am afraid.