# Best way to loop functions until failure?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, loops

Disclaimer:

1. I might be asking this question "the wrong way" - I'm still new
   to programming, so I might be lacking the correct terminology and
   understanding to ask the question properly. Sorry about that if I
   am.
2. I know you can't parse [X]HTML with regex. I'm not parsing
   it. I'm just matching a string to get the count of that string's line.
3. I've tried `lxml` and `iter()`, as well as `iterparse()`, and I've tried it [this way](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/index.html) and [this way](http://boscoh.com/programming/reading-xml-serially.html). It didn't work for me. I'm doing it this way.
4. I know the code here isn't efficient (specifically compiling the regex expression each time the function is called) - I've re-written it like this to provide the "minimum needed code" to ask the question, plus it makes it a little easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve I think.

With that all out the way; this code works and does what I want it to do, which is basically to take a huge set of xml records and turning it into a dictionary in the form of `{ record_id : {element_tag : element_val, element_tag : element_val, ...} }`.

Since the record_id is nested within the record itself, I first use the `record_splitter` to identify the count of `<RECORD>` and `</RECORD>` (the `beg` and `end`). I pass `beg` and `end` into `dic_factory` which finds these positions, does something with the elements nested within that, then sets 'beg' to `end +1`, and passes it back into the `record_splitter` function.

**My question** is whether there is a better way to implement this loop between functions, preferably under `if __name__ == '__main__'`, so that I can move more of my constants (e.g. the regex statements) under that as well.

```
Code:
    # stored as a text file, but here for clarity

    list_of_lines = """
    <RECORD>
      <TITLE>MISS</TITLE>
      <NAME>ELIZABETH</NAME>
      <SURNAME>II</SURNAME>
      <ADDRESS1>1 BUCKINGHAM PALACE</ADDRESS1>
      <ADDRESS2>LONDON</ADDRESS2>
      <ADDRESS3>GREATER LONDON</ADDRESS3>
      <POST_CODE>W1 11A</POST_CODE>
      <CASE_NUM>Q1QQ1234</CASE_NUM>
      <ID>32145698</ID>
      <LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2016-12-12</LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
     </RECORD>
     <RECORD>
      <TITLE>MR</TITLE>
      <NAME>PRINCE</NAME>
      <SURNAME>PHILLIP</SURNAME>
      <ADDRESS1>1 BUCKINGHAM PALACE</ADDRESS1>
      <ADDRESS2>LONDON</ADDRESS2>
      <ADDRESS3>GREATER LONDON</ADDRESS3>
      <POST_CODE>W1 11A</POST_CODE>
      <CASE_NUM>K5KK4321</CASE_NUM>
      <ID>56987412</ID>
      <LAST_UPDATE_DATE>2017-01-16</LAST_UPDATE_DATE>
     </RECORD>
     <RECORD>
    """

class recordManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.r_location = "list_of_lines.txt"

    def record_splitter(self, beg):

        re_beg_spl = re.compile(".*<RECORD>")
        re_end_spl = re.compile(".*(<\\/RECORD>)")

        end = None

        for count, line in enumerate( open(self.r_location) ):
            if count > beg:
                if re_end_spl.match(line):
                    end = count

                    if not re_end_spl.match(line):
                        if re_beg_spl.match(line):
                            beg = count
                    else:
                        break

                    recordManager.dic_factory(self, beg, end)


    def dic_factory(self, beg, end):

        re_casenum = re.compile(".*<CASE_NUM>(.*)<\\/CASE_NUM>")
        re_tag_val = re.compile(".*<(\\w*)>(.*)<.*")

        id_ = None
        tags = []
        vals = []

        for count, line in enumerate( open(self.r_location) ):

            if beg < count < end:
                if re_casenum.match(line):
                    m = re_casenum.match(line)
                    id_ = m.group(1)

                if re_tag_val.match(line):
                    m = re_tag_val.match(line)
                    tags.append( m.group(1) )
                    vals.append( m.group(2) )

        beg = end +1
        print {id_ : dict(zip(tags, vals)) }
        # {32145698 : {'POST_CODE': 'W1 11A', 'SURNAME': 'II', 'NAME': 'ELIZABETH', 'TITLE': 'MISS', 'ADDRESS1': '1 BUCKINGHAM PALACE', 'ADDRESS2': 'LONDON', 'ADDRESS3': 'GREATER LONDON', 'RECORD_TYPE': '1', 'CASE_NUM': 'Q1QQ1234', 'LAST_UPDATE_DATE': '2016-12-12', 'ID': '32145698'}}

        self.record_splitter(beg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst_fol = record_manager(file)
    recordManager.record_splitter(inst_folder, 0)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to loop 'beg' back into `record_splitter` outside of the functions / from **main**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst_fol = record_manager(file)
    beg, end = recordManager.record_splitter(inst_folder, 0)
```

Is this "looping from within functions" and if not, what's the better approach?

Comment: To clarify: are you asking how to get the variable `beg` back into the the function `record_splitter` *after* the initial call in `__main__` ?

Comment: That is correct - I want it to do this until it fails (i.e. until it has processed all of the lines within `list_of_lines.txt`)

Comment: With your end goal of putting xml into dict, you might check out: https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python , http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/xml/

Comment: Don't parse xml like a string! Learn how to use lxml or xml.etree to parse it and then build your dict. [See here for some ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684333/converting-xml-to-dictionary-using-elementtree/10076823)

Comment: @Ywapom that looks interesting, I will give it a shot. As long as it doesn't try and load the whole file into memory it might work. Thanks.

@Igle - I've given lxml a shot (see point 3 of the disclaimer). It loads the whole file into memory. Didn't work for me. Tried `iterparse()` with `clear()`. Also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest you use nested loops on the same iterator instead of separate functions. (details in comments)..

```
class recordManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.r_location = "list_of_lines.txt"
        self.records = [] #perhaps we want to store all the records we find?

    def find_records(self):

        re_beg_spl = re.compile(".*<RECORD>")
        re_end_spl = re.compile(".*(<\\/RECORD>)")
        re_casenum = re.compile(".*<CASE_NUM>(.*)<\\/CASE_NUM>") #move these up here since we're rolling the two functions into one
        re_tag_val = re.compile(".*<(\\w*)>(.*)<.*")

        with open(self.r_location) as f: #use the "with open() as f:" idiom to ensure file gets closed when you're done with it
            for line in f: #iterating over an open file defaults to line by line and we won't need line number with the nested loop approach
                if re_beg_spl.match(line): #start a new record
                    tags = {} #container for element tags and values
                    case = '' #case number for this record
                    for line in f: #re-use iterator for inner loop so lines are consumed (outer loop will pick up where inner loop leaves off)
                        match_case = re_casenum.match(line)
                        match_elem = re_tag_val.match(line)
                        match_end = re_end_spl.match(line)
                        if match_case:
                            case = match_case.group(1) #are match groups 1 or 0 indexed? I didn't look it up..
                        elif match_elem:
                            tags[match_elem.group(1)] = match_elem.group(2)
                        elif match_end: #end of a record -- save info and break out of inner loop
                            caseinfo = {case: tags}
                            print(caseinfo)
                            self.records.append(caseinfo)
                            break
```

Using this approach limits your need for effectively global variables (using an attribute of an object to pass state) which enforces more structure on your program (and keeps it simpler). This also eliminates re-looping over lines you've already examined, and re-reading files multiple times (which may be your speed limiting factor if you have a mechanical hard drive). I have not included checks for any possible break in the structure (missing end tag or id tag for example) but they could be added in a fairly straightforward manner.

Comment: Damn that's fast, elegant solution, and I've learnt something new (nesting loops). Thank you very much. Would you mind explaining this line please - `tags[match_elem.group(1)] = match_elem.group(2)`?

Comment: @rong [Here's](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python) a quick primer on python dictionaries. `tags` starts out as an empty dictionary each time a new record is started: `tags = {}`. I then use the first group of your `tag_val` regex as the key and the second group as the value for a new dictionary entry. Basically I'm incrementally adding values to the output dictionary rather than collecting the keys and values separately then creating the dict at the end with `dict(zip(tags, vals))` as you did in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: replace beg with self.beg**

My recommendation would be to make `beg` a field on your class. Remember, each method you are using has access to `self`, which is part of the advantage to organizing this work into a class in the first place:

so `__init__` becomes:

```
    def __init__(self):
    self.r_location = "list_of_lines.txt"
    self.beg = 0
```

Now everywhere where you use `beg` you refer to it as `self.beg`.

For example:

```
        for count, line in enumerate( open(self.r_location) ):
        if count > self.beg:
            if re_end_spl.match(line):
                end = count

                if not re_end_spl.match(line):
                    if re_beg_spl.match(line):
                        self.beg = count
                else:
                    break

                recordManager.dic_factory(self, self.beg, end)
```

Note that there is further opportunity for consolidation:
`dic_factory` takes `beg` as an argument, but it too has access to the object `self`, and could simply read `beg` off of that field.

Comment: Let me try this and come back to you. I am sure I've tried something of the like earlier, but there was an issue with changing the value of [self.beg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671218/python-class-methods-changing-self)